# Reading a PHP's serialized string

Tags: php, serialization

I'm trying to read a PHP serialized string. Here's the part of the string I'm trying to read:

```
 time|d:B.GIMKKIGLGPJJOJNOPGMIK;
```

However, it doesn't make sense to me. The data type doesn't seem to match what's in it?

The string is contained by serializing a session: `serialize($_SESSION)` where

```
$_SESSION['time'] = microtime(true);
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? How string is serialized?

Comment: @svlada, modified post to provide context.

Comment: Did you try $a = unserialize($SOME_SERIALIZED_DATA); echo $a['time']

Comment: this is weird..if I do this my output is `a:1:{s:4:"time";d:1361280938.605101108551025390625;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is strange. How do you unserialize your session? Code bellow outputs data fine.

```
$_SESSION['time'] = microtime(true);
$a = serialize($_SESSION);
$b = unserialize($a);
echo $b['time'];
```

Also you should read this article about session encode/decode: http://drupal.org/node/646702
and php manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-encode.php

Comment: I'm pulling the data directly from the database. Maybe this is a session issue - because it was serializing from `$_SESSION` ?

Comment: Can you post more code details, how you serialize and unserialize objects?

Comment: No objects were serialized, it was just the session that was serialized, and through the standard `serialize()` function. I grabbed the data directly from the database, but a session dump at the time indicates the same issue.

Comment: Ah, so, `session_encode()` is the closest to what I'll get. Though it doesn't explain show the session became poisoned.

Comment: Well session is not poisioned it's just encoded, read on php.net about session encoding http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-encode.php. You will get same output as yours.

Comment: Hi, I know that now - but, I'm guess that something happened in the session such that a key became messed up?